# locate entity in terms of coordinates of html through html parser

Tags: html

When we open a html file in browser it draw all entities written in html file. It calculates location of all entity and then draw using these location from some origin.

input :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Get location of below button after drawing by html parser
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>

{Output:  pixel coordinate of button entity}
```

Above code will draw a button , following text. Can we calculate this distance/location.
Now assume we need to show all coordinates/pixel of all entities from top-left to different platform, so that i can show it on different platform to user to let know that how many pixel they have moved and how many more they need to shift or change.

For this we need to parse html file and store all coordinates against this entity and dynamically show it on some different platform and when user change it on different platform it reflect on html file.

Comment: What? What languages are you using? What have you done so far? Post the html as well.

Comment: any language is fine , its more about how we can achieve this.I was thinking to implement html parser which is used to draw button/link in browser , the same html parser i will use to get location in terms of pixel but wont draw any thing.

Comment: both will work great. :)

Comment: But you want to do the parsing and representation yourself, or using a web browser?

Comment: I got the jquery library in which they provide position width height of all entity using each loop if jquery. which can server my purpose.

Comment: is there any way through i can execute a jquery script (fetching position width height) of  all entity through console. I dnt want to run html page on browser. i want to get details on console. like  $ Cmd <html-file> and o/p will be all console.log